# How to drag and drop an image into multiple cells WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am trying to figure out how to drag and drop an image into multiple cells (in a grid).
For example: I have an image that is 2 cells long. how do I drag it into 2 cells 
so half of it is in cell 1 and the other half is in cell 2?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the source of the image - another image control?

Comment: yes. There are few images.

Comment: @Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ can you help me?

Comment: Alright. Hold on... I'll see what I can come up with... I didn't have access to a desktop yesterday.

Comment: What type of a behavior do you want - continuous dragging of the control and snapping to cells... or ... drag and drop without the control moving during the drag but fitting into the cells when you release the mouse/trackpad button?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I would like the control (in my case its an image) to move during the drag. I want to be able to click on the image once drag the image along to the the target cell and click again and drop the image. If its a big image I would like it to span over two or more cells of the grid.

Comment: I was able to make the image follow along the drag movment and drop it by using a library I found online (I will post the source when I am at my desktop) but only if the mouse button pressed.

Comment: @ Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ library I am using is [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2006/12/08/drag-drop-library/)